# mint multiple NFT at a time

Tags: metaplex, mint, candymachine

I never saw (nor found anywhere) a solution to allow the user to mint more than one NFT at once using candy machine; any idea or hint to were can I look for this, if possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it anymore because Metaplex implemented an anti-bot fee on the Candy Machine.

A better answer is, that you can do it, but your users will pay the antibot fee for mint multiple tokens:

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/pull/417